# centOS can't install nodejs via yum

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, yum

I was using node v0.10.x on my centOS server and I want to update node.js, so followed some articles. First removing currently installed:

```
# which node
# cd /usr
# rm -r bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node.1
```

and then check node -v is not working, good. But using yum doesn't install latest Node.js, so I searched some post and found this:
https://www.metachris.com/2015/10/how-to-install-nodejs-5-on-centos-and-ubuntu/

so I followed commands:

```
# rpm -Uvh https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_5.x/el/7/x86_64/nodesource-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm
# yum install nodejs -y
```

and this is the problem. it prints numerous errors and keeps failing.

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 0:0.10.42-4.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs(x86-64) = 0.10.42-4.el6 for package:     nodejs-devel-0.10.42-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 0:5.11.1-1nodesource.el7.centos will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs-devel.x86_64 0:0.10.42-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package nodejs-devel.x86_64 0:5.11.1-1nodesource.el7.centos will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package         Arch      Version                          Repository     Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 nodejs          x86_64    5.11.1-1nodesource.el7.centos    nodesource    8.7 M
Updating for dependencies:
 nodejs-devel    x86_64    5.11.1-1nodesource.el7.centos    nodesource    7.6 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total size: 16 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/package.json from install of nodejs-5.11.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-semver-2.1.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/bin/semver from     install of nodejs-5.11.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-semver-2.1.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js from install of nodejs-5.11.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-semver-2.1.0-1.el6.noarch
  ... and keeps going on ...
```

Also before remove node, I also did this:

```
# npm cache clean -f
# npm install -g n
# n stable
```

but this isn't working at all, because always saying version 0.10.x, even downloaded latest one! ( I sawed 6.2.2 or something )

I think something messed up on my server and I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone gimme some advice? Also If can, I want to install latest Node.js.

Comment: You could try removing package *nodejs-semver-2.1.0-1.el6.noarch*

Comment: @J.J.Hakala **find / -name nodejs-semver-2.1.0-1.el6.noarch** results empty. is that a file?

Comment: @modernator, rpm packages are not saved as packages, they are installed to the destination (/usr/), and then deleted from the cache. ... Removing : # `yum remove nodejs-semver` ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install Node from the EPEL Repository

```
yum update
yum install epel-release
yum install nodejs
node --version
```

To access npm to manage their Node packages.

```
yum install npm
```

Comment: Hi @Haris I am getting `No package epel-release` available when running above command.

Comment: @NaveenKumar , Currently I am facing same issue while installing nodejs 'No package epel-release', were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: @user3534759 yes I directly downloaded the package from the node site and added it into the PATH.

Comment: Well this is working on Centos 7 in 2023

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), the "**Node Version Manager**".

In a shell, do:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

**Note**: *If you want to understand the script before running it, read the docs on [nvm github page](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and/or remove* `| bash` *from the curl command to read without running the .sh file*

Close and re-open shell to use updated profile. Then:

```
//prints "nvm" if correctly installed
$ command -v nvm

// install latest version of node
$ nvm install node

//check it's installed correctly
$ node -v
v12.6.0
```

After failing with other methods, this one had no issues.

Comment: Run source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh after install npm git get nvm command work as expected

Comment: This work for oracle cloud and all different serve. you saved my life and I fixed this for 1 month literally

Answer (score 2):

First, you must install epe-release

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

After, you can install node.js and npm

```
sudo yum -y install nodejs npm
```

Its worked for me.

Comment: I find out this for my centos 7 : No package nodejs available.
No package npm available.

Comment: @RajuyourPepe  following article will work for you 
https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-and-npm-on-centos/

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while on this on a Fedora 35 workstation (upgraded from Fedora 34),

```
$ yum repolist
nodesource                  Node.js Packages for Fedora Linux 34 - x86_64
```

it gave me

```
$ node --version       v12.22.1
```

None up the installers made a difference until I found this explanation:

[How To Install Node.js on Fedora 36/35/34](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-on-fedora/)

The tutorial includes 3 methods. It's the third one that worked for me.

### Install Node.js on Fedora via NVM

First, install the NVM tool on your system by running the following command:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

Then, reload the system environment using this command. It will set the required environment variables to use nvm on the system.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc 
$ nvm install v16.14 
Downloading and installing node v16.14.2...


$ node --version 
v16.14.2
```